# python cant check for more than one matching string

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to check for a string match with an if statement. My code looks like this:

```
labels = {"Channel 1": "", "Channel 2": "", "Channel 3": "", "Channel 4": ""}
for label in labels.keys():         
       if "Channel 1" or "Channel 2" == label:
            print("match")
       else:
            print("no match")
```

output:

```
match
match
match
match
```

I expect to get:

```
match
match
no match
no match
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Channel 1" or "Channel 2" == label` will evaluate to True because `"Channel 1"` as a string with content will always evaluate to True.

The order of operations here looks like this: `("Channel 1") or ("Channel 2" == label)`

What you want to do is one of these

```
if label == "Channel 1" or label == "Channel 2":
    pass
if label in ("Channel 1", "Channel 2"):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with this line:

```
if "Channel 1" or "Channel 2" == label:
```

Basically you are trying to check if "Channel 1" exists OR "Channel 2" equals label.

What you probably want instead is this:

```
if "Channel 1" == label or "Channel 2" == label:
```